# extracting text from comma separated values in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I have such kind of data in a text file:

```
12343,M,Helen Beyer,92149999,21,F,10,F,F,T,T,T,F,F
54326,F,Donna Noble,92148888,19,M,99,T,F,T,F,T,F,T
99999,M,Ed Harrison,92147777,28,F,5,F,F,F,F,F,F,T
88886,F,Amy Pond,92146666,31,M,2,T,F,T,T,T,T,T
37378,F,Martha Jones,92144444,30,M,5,T,F,F,F,T,T,T
22444,M,Tom Scully,92145555,42,F,6,T,T,T,T,T,T,T
81184,F,Sarah Jane Smith,92143333,22,F,5,F,F,F,T,T,T,F
97539,M,Angus Harley,92142222,22,M,9,F,T,F,T,T,T,T
24686,F,Rose Tyler,92142222,22,M,5,F,F,F,T,T,T,F
11113,F,Jo Grant,92142222,22,M,5,F,F,F,T,T,T,F
```

I want to extract the Initial of the first name and complete surname. So the output should look like:

```
H. Beyer, M
D. Noble, F
E. Harrison, M
```

The problem is that I should not use String Split function. Instead I have to do it using any other way of string handling.

This is my code:

```
Public Sub btn_IniSurGen_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_IniSurGen.Click
    Dim vFileName As String = "C:\temp\members.txt"
    Dim vText As String = String.Empty

    If Not File.Exists(vFileName) Then
        lbl_Output.Text = "The file " & vFileName & " does not exist"
    Else
        Dim rvSR As New IO.StreamReader(vFileName)
        Do While rvSR.Peek <> -1
            vText = rvSR.ReadLine() & vbNewLine
            lbl_Output.Text += vText.Substring(8, 1)
        Loop
        rvSR.Close()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: what's wrong with your code ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [TextFieldParserClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  It will parse the file and return the results directly to you as a string array.

```
Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.
    TextFieldParser("c:\logs\bigfile")

    MyReader.TextFieldType = 
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    MyReader.Delimiters = New String() {","}
    Dim currentRow As String()
    'Loop through all of the fields in the file.  
    'If any lines are corrupt, report an error and continue parsing.  
    While Not MyReader.EndOfData
        Try
            currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
            ' Include code here to handle the row. 
        Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
            MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & 
            " is invalid.  Skipping")
        End Try 
    End While 
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

For your wanted result, you may changed

```
lbl_Output.Text += vText.Substring(8, 1)
```

to

```
'declare this first
Dim sInit as String
Dim sName as String


sInit = vText.Substring(6, 1)
sName = ""
For x as Integer = 8 to vText.Length - 1
  if vText.Substring(x) = "," Then Exit For
  sName &= vText.Substring(x)
Next

lbl_Output.Text += sName & ", " & sInit
```

But better you have more than one lbl_Output ...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
    Dim lines As New List(Of String)
    For Each s As String In File.ReadAllLines("textfile3.txt")
        Dim temp As String = ""
        s = s.Substring(s.IndexOf(","c) + 1)
        temp = ", " + s.First
        s = s.Substring(s.IndexOf(","c) + 1)
        temp = s.First + ". " + s.Substring(s.IndexOf(" "c), s.IndexOf(","c) - s.IndexOf(" "c)) + temp
        lines.Add(temp)
    Next
```

The list `Lines` will contain the strings you need.